# scapy generated overly large sequence number, while actual setting is different

Tags: python, virtualbox, scapy

I have 3 virtualbox(ubuntu16) connected each other through private Nat, and two of them has established telnet connection. The third one can already catch the packets sending between these two, and I want to use the third machine generate a RST packet to terminate their connection, but I encounter following problem.

this is the sending package from 10.0.2.14 to 10.0.2.16, with ACK=6, seq=3.
[image]

So presumably, I want to generate a RST packet send from 10.0.2.16 to 10.0.2.14.

this is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from scapy.all import *

ip = IP(src="10.0.2.16", dst="10.0.2.14")
tcp = TCP(sport=23, dport=37568, flags="R", seq=6, ack=3)
pkt = ip/tcp

ls(pkt)
send(pkt, verbose=0)
```

This is the python3 output:[image]

This is what I capture inside the wireshark[image]

It has the right ACK but wrong SEQ, and this is probably the reason I can't terminate their connection

Comment: If you've established the connection with telnet then initial sequence
numbers are randomly generated and most probably do not start at 0.
Wireshark displays relative ack number (i.e., the difference with the
initial sequence number).  This is why when you set it to 3, you see
this huge seqeunce number displayed by wireshark but the real number
that appears in the hexdump of your frame should indeed by 3.

Comment: If the problem is due to sequence numbers, maybe you could try instead to capture packets (with `sniff`).  Then
you can send and `RST` packet with the appropriate sequence number by looking at the sequence number in the packet you capture.

Comment: @qouify thank you so much it is the wireshark relative sequence problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Wireshark problem, wireshark shows the relative sequence, what you can do is to right click the sequence number, and uncheck "relative sequence number", and wireshark will show you the abs sequence number.